# Why Fingers glitch to the wrong direction when project saved?

Tags: rendering, animation, scripting, rigging

Why do the fingers just decides to go back to the default position after I saved Blender and restart it ever time?

Like after I spend all my precious time posing the fingers the way I want, and I save and closed Blender and open it another day, only to see the fingers have reset back to the default pose.

[image]

Comment: Is he rigged and in that case have you keyframed the bones? Maybe share the file?

Comment: he is rigged of course

Comment: Maybe you have keyframed your fingers before? Please share the .blend file via [Blend Exchange](https://blend-exchange.com)

Comment: aww, i think i see what's the problem, it's just i didn't turn on auto keying

Comment: You can also key manually by pressing `I`.

Comment: There is no "of course" if you don't tell us :) Has this problem been solved now?

Comment: sorry CoreRage, but you didn't give us ANY technical information what you did and how you did it, so pls provide blend file - because we cannot magically guess what you did and not providing necessary informations doesn't make a good question - so i can only downvote that question.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't write in all caps in the title or body of any posts, it is the written equivalent of shouting, is [harder to read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Readability) and may be [considered rude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Computing). Please use the [edit] button below the post to change you text into regular case.

Comment: Hey, so the problem was i forgot to turn on Blender's Out Keying, because i thought i had it  turn on all this time, like i said on march 13, it's has been solved. sorry for not replying sooner i was afk